# Women participation in Sports?

Tags: practical-islam, women, sports

This matters mummers around quite usually around muslim Women. Does Islam allows women to participate in Sports, like Olympic or Fifa games, given that the [dress code](http://islam.ru/en/content/story/dress-code-muslim-women) is followed properly?

This question becomes little broad when connected with the concepts of sects in Islam, since Dress code of women is followed differently.

Is there any specific order(fatwa, Hadith or Ayah, against this?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything in the Quran or Hadith that prohibits women from participating in sports. Indeed there is a Sahih hadith in which Ayesha narrates that she *raced* with the Prophet.

> Narrated Aisha, Ummul Mu'minin:
>
> While she was on a journey along with the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ): I
>   had a race with him (the Prophet) and I outstripped him on my feet.
>   When I became fleshy, (again) I had a race with him (the Prophet) and
>   he outstripped me. He said: This is for that outstripping.
>
> [ [Sunan Abu Daud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/15/102),  [Ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1262980) ]

Comment: with respect, this answer does not provide enough guidance to understand the problem asked in the question.